# How to manage security of model, such as only sales manager should be able to create, delete, write and read those records in odoo 10

Tags: odoo-10

I am new in odoo and want know how to manage security in module,
O have created one model and now gives group that can only see my
record view, see below code that I have tried,

```
<record id="view_account_supplier_payment_tree" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name">account.supplier.payment.tree</field>
        <field name="model">account.payment</field>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <tree decoration-info="state=='draft'" decoration-muted="state=='reconciled'" edit="false">
                <field name="payment_date"/>
                <field name="name"/>
                <field name="journal_id"/>
                <field name="payment_method_id"/>
                <field name="partner_id" string="Vendor"/>
                <field name="amount" sum="Amount"/>
                <field name="company_id" groups="base.group_multi_company"/>
                <field name="state"/>
                <field name="currency_id" invisible="1"/>
                <field name="partner_type" invisible="1"/>
            </tree>
        </field>
    </record>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make an ir.model.access.csv file to manage security,
this file also mention in manifest file.